# ProgressBar as health javafx

Tags: java, javafx

First my code, down is explanation:

```
GridPane gp = new GridPane();
gp.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

ProgressBar pb1 = new ProgressBar(1);
ProgressBar pb2 = new ProgressBar(1);
Button btn1 = new Button("Player 1");
Button btn2 = new Button("Player 2");

gp.add(pb1, 1, 0);
gp.add(pb2, 2, 0);
gp.add(btn1, 1, 1);
gp.add(btn2, 2, 1);

btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        pb2.setProgress(pb2.getProgress() - 0.1);
    }
});

btn2.setOnAction(e -> {
    pb1.setProgress(pb1.getProgress() - 0.1);
});

Scene scene = new Scene(gp, 250, 200);
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Okey, as you can see I have two progress bar(health) and two buttons. When I click on Player1 program need to reduce progress bar on player two(random value, I put 0.1 because I have problem with random), and same on another side, with player2.

So, my problem is:

- how to make program to reduce random value
- when I reduce to the end progress bar, I got blue line which goes left to right without stopping.
- end, I want to print message who wins at the end of program

Thank you! If I explained something bad sorry, and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Regarding the second point, that animated blue line is used when the progress is indeterminate (i.e. `progress < 0`). To stop that from happening don't let the progress drop below zero.

Comment: Okey, i understand you, but can you help mi a little bit with code, I'm new with javafx

Comment: I make random value, I need just to fix this when my value goes under zero, are u still here?

Comment: One option is `setHealth(Math.max(0.0, newHealth))`.

Comment: Okey, its not going good, never mind, can you help mi when user has zero? I make if statement with message when user has zero 'health' but program send me message when i  run it

Comment: You can use [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) and [nextDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble--) for generating a random value.

Comment: I made random value, and I have problem just with this blue line which goes left to right without stopping

Comment: Check the value for `value < 0` before setting it to the progressbar or use the method Slaw provided.